# Query "like" and "or" in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch for filtering and searching from json file and I am newbie in this technology. So I am little bit confused how to write like query in elasticsearch.

```
select * from table_name where 'field_name1' like 'a%' or 'field_name2' like 'a%'
```

This is oracle query. How do I write this query in Elasticsearch? I am using elasticsearch version 6.8.13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use the [Elasticsearch Wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) query, combined inside a [Bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).
In case you're new, `should` in Elasticsearch bool query context is pretty much equals to `OR` in SQL language.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "field_name1": {
                            "value": "a*"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "field_name2": {
                            "value": "a*"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wildcard searches are slow. Avoid using wildcards at the beginning of your strings. You can use prefix query instead.